# Why did ActiveRecord::Relation remove array_delegable? in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 4, ActiveRecord::Relation automatically delegated array methods like `slice`, so you could say, for example `SomeModel.where(prop: 'value').slice(0, 10)`

That has been removed in Rails 5.  Why?

Here is the relevant code in ActiveRecord::Relation in rails 4:

```
def array_delegable?(method)
  Array.method_defined?(method) && BLACKLISTED_ARRAY_METHODS.exclude?(method)
end

def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if @klass.respond_to?(method)
    scoping { @klass.public_send(method, *args, &block) }
  elsif array_delegable?(method)
    to_a.public_send(method, *args, &block)
  elsif arel.respond_to?(method)
    arel.public_send(method, *args, &block)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

And here it is in Rails 5:

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if @klass.respond_to?(method)
    scoping { @klass.public_send(method, *args, &block) }
  elsif arel.respond_to?(method)
    arel.public_send(method, *args, &block)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

(Note: I tried to post this question in the Rails forum, but apparently registration is broken there and there is no way to ask for help)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple commits with brief explanations:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/95c24e9f9aed36b2ee650dbf779cf56dcdbbede3

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d79334a1dee67e31222c790e231772deafcaeb8

Seems like there should be an addition to the Changelog though.  I didn't see this mentioned in there.